# Unify generic types in macro

Tags: macros, haxe

I wanted to use macro to check if a function is returning a particular generic type, say `Array`, so it is fine if the function is returning `Array<Dynamic>`, `Array<String>`, or even generic `Array<T>`.

So I tried to `Context.unify` it with `Array<Dynamic>`. It is fine for `Array<String>` or `Array<Dynamic>` but it fails when the type parameter is "generic" because the ComplexType `Array<T>` won't convert to a Type with `Type not found: T` (See code below). Are there any possible ways to achieve what I am attempting to do?

```
package;

#if macro
import haxe.macro.Context;
using haxe.macro.ComplexTypeTools;
#end

#if !macro @:build(Macros.build()) #end
class Main 
{
    public function test<T>():Array<T>
    {
        return [];
    }
}

class Macros
{
    public static function build()
    {
        #if macro
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        for(field in fields)
        {
            switch(field.kind)
            {
                case FFun(f):
                    // try to unify Array<String> with Array<Dynamic>
                    trace(Context.unify((macro:Array<String>).toType(), (macro:Array<Dynamic>).toType())); 
                    // true

                    // try to unify Array<T> with Array<Dynamic>
                    trace(Context.unify(f.ret.toType(), (macro:Array<Dynamic>).toType())); 
                    // Type not found: T
                default:
            }
        }
        return null;
        #end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

So, checking TPath was not the best idea. 
Based on the previous assumption about Dynamic being assignable to any type we can replace unconvertable type parameter with the Dynamic (eg `Array<T>` = `Array<Dynamic>`) and when try to unify it.

```
static function toTypeExt(c:ComplexType):Null<haxe.macro.Type>
{
    try {
        return c.toType();          
    } catch (error:Error)
    {                   
        switch (c)                          
        {
            case TPath(p):                  
                //deep copy of the TPath with all type parameters as Dynamic
                var paramsCopy = [for (i in 0...p.params.length) TPType(macro:Dynamic)];
                var pCopy:TypePath = {
                    name: p.name,
                    pack: p.pack,
                    sub: p.sub,
                    params: paramsCopy
                }
                var cCopy = TPath(pCopy);

                //convert after
                return cCopy.toType();
            default:                    
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Use **toTypeExt()**  in your build macro instead of toType.

```
trace(Context.unify(toTypeExt(f.ret), (macro:Array<Dynamic>).toType()));
```

Looks more like a workaround to me, but there is a strange thing about ComplexTypeTools.toType - it will succeed with a class type parameter while failing with method type parameter.

### OLD ANSWER

Unification won't work since there is no way of converting ComplexType with the type parameter to Type (in that context). But since you are unifying with Array it is safe to assume that any Array will unify with it (since any type is assignable to Dynamic http://haxe.org/manual/types-dynamic.html).

---

May be it is not the *pritiest* solution, but simple TPath check is the way to go here:

```
    case FFun(f):                   
        switch (f.ret) {
                case TPath({ name: "Array", pack: [], params: _ }):
                    trace("Yay!");
                default:                            
        }
```

Comment: Your approach only consider the syntactic type name but not its real type. The problem is that it won't work if the "name" of the type is not "Array", for example `typedef MyType<T> = Array<T>` where MyType is actually an Array only with a different name.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my solution is not considering a lot of things. Also, while trying to solve this i came across a weird thing: if you promote <T> to be a class type parameter when toType() will succeed and Context.unify (with Array<Dynamic>) will return true.

Comment: I see, so the solution is to replace T with Dynamic before turning it into a Type. Seems good enough, thanks!